# Thrift in production: high availability model

Tags: thrift, amazon-elb

Trying to learn how to setup high availability, Blue/Green deploys and horizontal scaling of Thrift services for Production. How can one use Thrift on multiple servers and have the clients use multiple server nodes and automatically switch to healthy ones in a failure scenario?

I have read the [thrift tutorials](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/), [thrift missing guide](https://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/) and even [the Learning Apache Thrift book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1785882740). In addition random googling hasn't brought up answers.

I did find a partial solution from [node-thrift-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thrift-pool), but it would only allow one to add multiple servers to a pool. But once you're deploying a new version, that pool would become empty because the Client side would not know about the new servers (hence needing a ELB or something similar) . I have tried using an ELB and am failing to get it working, will be enabling and inspecting access logs after this to dig deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can one use Thrift on multiple servers and have the clients use multiple server nodes and automatically switch to healthy ones in a failure scenario?

In short: By setting up an appropriate architecture.

To some extent you are asking the wrong question. Thrift is only a mechanism that enables two endpoints, typically a client and a server, to communicate with each other by means of some standardized "building blocks".

What Apache Thrift can **not** do, is providing a fully fledged infrastructure for you to - just as an example - implement a sophisticated workload scheduler like [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/)<sup>1)</sup> or some distributed, fault-tolerant two-phase-commit protocol like Paxos or Raft. All of that is located (at least) one abstraction level higher.

Even the infrastructure to have a group of peer machines talking to each other ("[gossip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol)") is something that has to be built on top of the RPC or messaging layer. This is completely regardless of the combination of software used, be it Thrift over Sockets or a message bus, or be it the proverbial [Avian Carriers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6214).

In other words, Apache Thrift can provide the infrastructure to let you send messages from one point to another very efficiently, through various channels, in all kinds of formats. If you need some logic on top of that, then this is of course possible, but some other piece of code will be needed to achieve that. Thrift gives a very capable swiss knife, but you still will have to cut the tree.

PS: Randy Abernethy's [Programmer's Guide to Apache Thrift](https://www.manning.com/books/the-programmers-guide-to-apache-thrift) is also worth a look. I don't know the other book, so I can't really compare them.

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>Mesos actually uses protobuf. But that's an unimportant detail here.</sub>

Comment: I understand that thrift doesnt build the infrastructure for me. I was looking for something along the lines of an explanation of what the infrastructure looks like to allow those things for thrift services.  ex: does one get HA/Failover w/ aws elbs or is there a different model that works? Same with scaling, what technologies would be used to distribute load amongst N thrift services (on different servers)?

Answer (score 0):

The [harpc](https://github.com/baifendian/harpc) is a choice, but without python3 support